# Socket.io: Events firing twice if used inside an express route

Tags: javascript, express, websocket, socket.io

I'm working on a chat app in socketio. The issue i'm stuck in is that if i put my `io.on('connection', ..})` block outside the express route `app.get('/chat')`, everything works fine but when i put it inside the route `/chat`. everything inside the connection is firing twice.

**server.js**

```
 // On new connection
 io.on("connection", socket => {
      console.log('Socket ID: ' + socket.id);
      // I want the user object (inside /chat route) to be available here..
 })

// @route:chat
app.get("/chat", auth, async (req, res) => {
    const user = User.findbyId(req.userId);
    // socket.io part moved outside the route

    res.render('chat', {})
})
```

Output on first request to `/chat`:

```
Socket ID: 5e82d1a21c9d4400003e9bce
```

Output on second request to `/chat`:

```
Socket ID: 5e82d1a21c9d4400003e9bce --> this is repeating
Socket ID: 5e82d1a21c9d4400003e9bc4
```

And so on if i keep requesting `/chat`.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: It's because you're registering two event handlers to for on('connection'). Put it outside of the route.

Comment: YEp, you're answering to your question in the title...

Comment: I want to use the io.on("connection") inside the route

Comment: @i.brod where I'm registering two event handlers?

Comment: In your GET /chat route. Each time a request goes to this route, you're registering another handler for io.on('connection')

Comment: socketIO doesn't overwrite the existing handler, it adds another one. SocketIO setup should be done outside of the routes generally.

Comment: so if i have a user object only available in the /chat route,  how could i pass that to inside the socket.io connection handler (which will be outside the route)

Comment: I'm not familiar with your application structure, so it's very hard to say anything useful here. Can you provide some piece of code that illustrates your "flow"?

Comment: @i.brod i updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, socketIO operations shouldn't depend on an express route. If you want a user to join the socketIO connection, it should be done via SocketIO's event handlers. Your front-end should initiate the connection, and pass some identity to SocektIO, if you want to associate a "user" to that socket.

I don't know how your application handles auth, but a common practice is to pass a token to the SocketIO connection establishment:

```
const socket = IO.connect('http://localhost:8000', {
    query: {
      token//This token will be available on the server.
    }
  });
```

So then in your server:

```
const middleware = async (socket,next)=>{
    const token = socket.handshake.query.token;//Now you have the user token, which presumably contains the user ID.

    const verifiedUser = await getUserByToken(token);//Let's say this returns a user object, if the token is valid, false if not.
    // Let's assume that behind the scenes this function also calls User.findbyId(id);

    if(verifiedUser){
        socket.userObject = verifiedUser;//You can place the userObject on the token object, to be used later.
        next()//Will allow the "connection" event to proceed.
    }else{
        next(new Error('INVALID_CREDENTIALS'))//Will cause the on("error") event to fire in the front-end, passing this error.
        //The on("connection") event here will not fire.
    }
}

io.use(middleware)

io.on('connection', async (socket) => { 

    //This runs only if middleware is "successful".


})
```

I don't know if this really answers your questions, but it's an example for how a socket-user relationship might look like.